# Kivy: dimming Android navigation buttons

Tags: android, python, kivy

I would like to dim navigation buttons in Kivy application. How to do it in Java is described here: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/dim.html
But I wasn't able to figure out how to do it in Kivy using pyjnuis or something else.
Anyone has done this before?

Thanks

Comment: If you are writing a Kivy app, you are not writing Java nor xml but just kv lang for the layout : http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html and Python

Comment: @GerardRozsavolgyi The question is about accessing this part of the android api from a kivy app, which is a legitimate question in principle and is not related to the construction of the kivy ui.

Comment: ok confused by the term to "dim", sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this via pyjnius. The only thing to watch out for is that you cannot modify Android UI components from outside the UI thread.

To start with, you'll use pyjnius to import the Java classes:

```
from jnius import autoclass
PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
View = autoclass('android.view.View')
```

Then the SystemUI can be modified (from the UI thread only):

```
PythonActivity.mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView()
    .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE)
```

Here is a full example:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from jnius import autoclass
PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
View = autoclass('android.view.View')

from android.runnable import run_on_ui_thread

root = Builder.load_string('''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: 'Dim'
        on_press: app.dim()
    Button:
        text: 'Undim'
        on_press: app.undim()
''')

class DimTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root

    @run_on_ui_thread
    def set_systemui_visibility(self, options):
        PythonActivity.mActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(options)

    def dim(self, *args):
        self.set_systemui_visibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE)

    def undim(self, *args):
        self.set_systemui_visibility(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DimTestApp().run()
```

<s>[You can download a test APK if you'd like](http://wikisend.com/download/797956/DimTest-1.0.0-debug.apk) (link valid until 2015-04-09).</s>